# Why is the HR delaying in rolling out the offer letter inspite of me clearing the technical rounds?

Tags: job-offer

I'm an experienced professional ànd I applied on the company's website for a certain job opening. My profile got shortlisted and I gave 1 technical written test, 1 telephonic interview (technical) , 2 face to face technical interviews. Post the 2nd interview, the I was told that i'm selected and they'll be rolling out the offer soon. However it's been 2 weeks and I've still not heard anything from the HR. I called them 3-4 times but they kept on delaying giving some excuse. What should I do?

Comment: How did the HR at this company define "soon"? At any of the times you called, did they give you any better estimates?

Comment: Could be any number of reasons - holidays, management sign-off, another possible candidate, budget problems.

Comment: Honestly, 2 weeks is not that long. Sometimes paperwork just takes time.

Comment: unfortunately, it **CAN** take that long.  **BUT** it's totally possible they have just decided on something else.  "I was told that i'm selected" -  talk means absolutely nothing, unfortunately  :/

Answer (score 4):

> What should I do?

In this case, I think you are best served by continuing your job search as if *this one has been lost*.

> Why is the HR delaying?

Who knows what might have happened.  They may have an *internal candidate* that surfaced, the hiring manager may have changed their mind, or the position's budget may have been cut, etc.  I will say it is not *necessarily a reflection on you*.

So, continue looking for work as if this opportunity has passed.  If it still works out, great, it not you are still keeping the fire burning.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the size of the company this could be a whole range of possibilities. Most likely it’s due to red tape and waiting for the correct people to approve and sign things. If it starts stretching out ridiculously long you might be able to talk to someone else that isn’t HR. Potentially your new manager if you can get their details and see what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

First off, Mister Positive is right.  You’re not yet committed nor are they.  Keep your options open.

We just don’t have the info to answer.  There are clues you might provide such as company size, industry or other details about them.  But ultimately, it comes down each company.

- It may be that they’re waffling on actually hiring the position. 
  This might be a red flag around budgeting or a yellow flag about
  bureaucracy.
- It may just be (IMHO poor) process.  I had an employer
  who would not order equipment (computer, phone, etc.) in time for
  first week use.
- Related to process, it may be someone missed a step
  or approval along the way and HR doesn’t want to share that error
  with you.
- There may be background checks, though I’d think they’d divulge that.
- It could even be researching legal concerns.  They may be ensuring they have followed a standard process.  They might be considering that there are no anti-discrimination rules they’ve missed.  Some scenarios like visa sponsorship may not be fully known.

It sounds like something odd going on here, but I wouldn’t recommend walking away solely on supposition if you like the rest of the situation.  You might consider requesting a follow-up conversation when the offer does come.  Before accepting, you could then raise your concern.  If they retract it, you probably dodged a bullet.  If it’s just HR being odd—it may be a non-issue.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is continue applying and interviewing for other jobs. That is the part of your situation you have control over - do not lose focus of that.

I have personally been, more than once, in almost identical scenarios where the offer never materialised. Look out for number one and continue to look for alternatives.